# Concept of Redux Reducer | Is it against the rules to import constant in reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux

Is it correct if we use CONSTANT which was imported and added inside of this reducer?

```
import { SOME_CONST } from './SOME_CONST'

    export const reducer = (state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
      case types.SOME_TYPE:
        return {
          ...state,
          key: SOME_CONST,
        }
       default:
        return state
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. See the official [shopping-cart](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/reducers/cart.js) example. They import the action type constants and use them in reducers. A key principle is that the reducer must be kept pure and idempotent.

```js
import {
  ADD_TO_CART,
  CHECKOUT_REQUEST,
  CHECKOUT_FAILURE
} from '../constants/ActionTypes'

const initialState = {
  addedIds: [],
  quantityById: {}
}

const addedIds = (state = initialState.addedIds, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1) {
        return state
      }
      return [ ...state, action.productId ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// ...
```

Comment: Ur example is for types. What about a state? When we add constants to a state